# Create new object from two tables JDO DataNucleus

Tags: java, persistence, jdo, dto, datanucleus

I am attempting to create a DTO object by persisting two classes using DataNucleus.

The DTO I wish to create:

```
@PersistenceAware
DtoObject{

   Protected String Id;  //populated by Order class
   Protected String status; //populated by Order class
   Protected String phoneNumber; //populated by Customer class
   Protected String address;  //populated by Customer class
}
The Objects:

 @PersistenceCapable
 @FetchGroup(name="dto", members = {@Persistent(name = "Id"), 
 @Persistent(name="status")})
 public Class Order{
   @PrimaryKey
   @Persistent
   private String Id;
   @Persistent
   private String status;
   @Persistent
   private Customer customer;
}

@PersistenceCapable
@FechGroup(name="dto", members = { @Persistent(name = "phoneNumber"),
@Peristent(name="address") })
public Class Customer{

   @PrimaryKey
   @Persistent
   private String Id;
   @Persistent
   private String phoneNumber;
   @Persistent
   private string Address;
}
```

The JDODL:

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(Order.class);
            pm.getFetchPlan().setGroup("dto");
            q.setUnique(true);
            q.setFilter("Id == id");
            q.declareParameters("String id");
            q.setResultClass(DtoObject.class);
            DtoObject dto = (DtoObject)q.execute(id);
```

I can populate the dto object with its attributes mapped to the Order.class but can not get the attributes from the Customer.class. Data Nucleus joins the tables and selects the proper columns from each table but leaves the phoneNumber =null and address = null;

Pointers on how to make this work with one query will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Query q = pm.newQuery("SELECT UNIQUE this.id, this.status, " + 
    " this.customer.phoneNumber, this.customer.address INTO " + 
    DtoObject.class.getName() + 
    " FROM " + Order.class.getName() + " WHERE this.id = :id");
DtoObject dto = (DtoObject)q.execute(idParam);
```

Assuming the result class (DtoObject) obeys [the conditions of a result class](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2/jdo/jdoql_result.html)